# How to add if else or case in SQL select statement

Tags: sql

This is my SQL query to fetch data from the tables order and user_master

```
String str = "select od.total, od.invoice_link, od.status, ";
str += "od.order_type, um.name as sender_name, umr.name as receiver_name, ";
str += "umr.twitter_handle as receiver_twitter_handle, um.twitter_handle as sender_twitter_handle ";
str += "from orders od ";
str += "join user_master um on um.id = od.user_id ";
str += "join user_master umr on umr.id = od.receiver_id ";
str += "where user_id = '"+user_id+"' ";

String json = dao.getResultJSON(str);
return json;
```

In the database there is this column named order_type which contains values like  transfer, request and invoice.I need to return "Payment to" into the variable json if the value in the order_type column is 'transfer' and 'Requested from' if the value in the column is 'request'.Just forget about 'invoice' which i mentioned above.These two will be enough for my expected output..

Anyway thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: For a SQL question, please post executable SQL statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select od.total, 
       od.invoice_link, od.status,
       od.order_type,
       um.name as sender_name, umr.name as receiver_name,
       umr.twitter_handle as receiver_twitter_handle, 
       um.twitter_handle as sender_twitter_handle 
  from orders od 
  join user_master um on um.id = od.user_id 
  join user_master umr on umr.id = od.receiver_id 
  where user_id = SOMETHING
```

is your SQL query dissected out from what appears to be Java. You should understand that SQL deals in tables; that is, it deals in rectangles full of data. Each result set returns a series of rows. Each row in a result set necessarily must have the same columns as the other rows.

You are asking for two different kinds of rows, one with a `Payment to` column and the other with a `Requested from` column.  The choice of row depends on some data in the row. This is not going to happen in a single query.

You can do something like this, though.

```
select 
 ...,
 CASE WHEN od.order_type='transfer' THEN receiver_twitter_handle ELSE '' END `Payment to`,
 CASE WHEN od.order_type='request' THEN sender_twitter_handle ELSE '' END `Requested from`,
 ...
```

This will yield the two columns you want in every row of your result set. One, or both, the columns will contain blanks when irrelevant.

The details of these `CASE` statements can vary among makes of table server, and you haven't disclosed which one you're using, so there may be a mistake here. But you can fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your time to make me understand.I made the changes and its working just fine.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing where `payment_to` and `requested_from` are supposed to come from, here is as shot in the dark:

```
select 
    od.total
  , od.invoice_link
  , od.status
  , od.order_type
  , um.name as sender_name
  , umr.name as receiver_name
  , um.twitter_handle as sender_twitter_handle 
  , umr.twitter_handle as receiver_twitter_handle
  , case when od.order_type = 'transfer' then od.payment_to else null end as payment_to 
  , case when od.order_type = 'request' then od.requested_from else null end as requested_from
  from orders od 
    inner join user_master um on um.id = od.user_id 
    inner join user_master umr on umr.id = od.receiver_id 
  where user_id = '"+user_id+"'
```

In the format you posted:

```
String str = "select";
str += "    od.total";
str += "  , od.invoice_link";
str += "  , od.status";
str += "  , od.order_type";
str += "  , um.name as sender_name";
str += "  , umr.name as receiver_name";
str += "  , um.twitter_handle as sender_twitter_handle ";
str += "  , umr.twitter_handle as receiver_twitter_handle";
str += "  , case when od.order_type = 'transfer' then od.payment_to else null end as payment_to";
str += "  , case when od.order_type = 'request' then od.requested_from else null end as requested_from";
str += "  from orders od ";
str += "    inner join user_master um on um.id = od.user_id ";
str += "    inner join user_master umr on umr.id = od.receiver_id ";
str += "  where user_id = '"+user_id+"';";

String json = dao.getResultJSON(str);
return json;
```